# A formulation of partial derivative in RNN

Tags: nlp, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

The recurrent computation from hidden state $h_{j-1}$ to $h_j$ is:
$$ h_j = W f(h_{j-1}) + W^{(hx)} x_{[j]} $$,
where `W` is the parameter matrix between two hidden states, and `$W^{(hx)}$` is the parameter matrix between input vector `x` and hidden state `h`. $h_j$ and $x_{[j]}$ are the hidden state and input vector of jth layer.

I saw a particle derivative formulation in the Recurrent Neural Network as following:

$$\frac{\partial{h_j}}{h_{j-1}} = W^T diag(f'(h_{j-1}))$$

I think it should be `$W diag(f'(h_{j-1}))$` not `$W^T diag(f'(h_{j-1}))$`. Why should we use the transpose of `W`?

Comment: Will the dimension matches in matrix multiplication if you don't transpose?

Comment: Yes, W is a square matrix, since each hidden layer has the same dimension.

Comment: I know it is not possible, but what if it is not squared. You could also use the scalar form of the equation to check.

Comment: btw it is not a good place here to ask math question. try http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: oh, thank you very much.

Comment: But I think the transpose version would not match the dimension.